# Post-Condition in test cases

Tags: manual-testing

Is it fine not have any post-condition in a test case? 
For example, there is an employee information system or module and an employee can login into the system and views his/her profile and logs out.
If I write a test case for it, I can't think of any post-condition possible in this test case. Can I write it without post-condition?

Comment: Your example has a clear post-condition. The user must be logged out after the run, which means any stated that you've set while he was logged in must be undone, such as authentication cookies for example. I can't think by heart now of a test-worthy case which doesn't have a post condition. Give us more examples of what you mean, so we can argument and make it clearer for you.

Comment: You are right, actually, I was not much clear about test cases and its details, but now it's clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Successful logout, for one.

No user data left on the screen (or other, like history).

Ready to login again.

(I assume you are already testing the user got the right info.)